# Scanf() optional further input (separated by space)

Tags: c

What would be the easiest way to consider user input.  Sometimes the action that I would like to take requires an input of "print" from the user, but other times I need something like "add  input1 input2".

If I do something like:
`success = fscanf(stdin,"%s %s %s", cmd, input1, input2)`
the program will continue on until there are three things inputted every time.  The menu for the program is built around comparing strings to the value main_input, but often times the optional inputs are not needed.

Example of what I am talking about:

```
    int echo = 0;                                // controls echoing, 0: echo off, 1: echo on
    if(argc > 1 && strcmp("-echo",argv[1])==0) { // turn echoing on via -echo command line option
    echo=1;
  }
    printf("TreeMap Editor\n");
    printf("Commands:\n");
    printf("  quit:            exit the program\n");
    printf("  print:           shows contents of the tree in reverse sorted order\n");
    printf("  add <key> <val>: inserts the given key/val into the tree, duplicate keys are ignored\n");
    printf("  get <key>:       prints FOUND if the name is in the tree, NOT FOUND otherwise\n");
    printf("  clear:           eliminates all key/vals from the tree\n");
    printf("  size:            prints the total number of nodes in the tree\n");
    printf("  preorder:        prints contents of the tree in pre-order which is how it will be saved\n");
    printf("  save <file>:     writes the contents of the tree in pre-order to the given file\n");
    printf("  load <file>:     clears the current tree and loads the one in the given file\n");
  
    char cmd[128];
    char input1[128];
    char input2[128];
    treemap_t treemap;
    int success;
    treemap_init(&treemap);

    while(1){
        printf("TM> ");                 // print prompt
        success = fscanf(stdin,"%s %s %s",cmd, input1, input2); // read a command
        if(success==EOF){                 // check for end of input
            printf("\n");                   // found end of input
            break;                          // break from loop
        }

        if( strcmp("quit", cmd)==0 ){     // check for exit command
            if(echo){
                printf("quit\n");
            }
            printf("quit\n");
            break;                          // break from loop
        }

        else if( strcmp("print", cmd)==0 ){ // insertion
            if(echo){
                printf("what!!! %s\n",cmd);
            }
            printf("hellur?\n");

        }

        else if( strcmp("add", cmd)==0 ){     // get command
            if(echo){
                printf("im in add");
                }
            printf("Your variables are: %s %s\n", input1, input2);
        }
    



        else{                                 // unknown command
            if(echo){
                printf("%s\n",cmd);
            }
         printf("unknown command %s\n",cmd);
    }

    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if you run this program and input "Quit" for example, it should just exit out of the program right then and there.  However, it will wait for 2 other inputs before it compares the inputted string to cmd.

From what I have read I may need to do something with fgets()??  I am a novice programmer and I cannot make sense of this at the moment.

Comment: "What would be the easiest way to consider user input." not to use `scanf` at all. Read the whole line with `fgets` and then you can use different functions to parse the line depending on your needs, functions like `sscanf`, `strtok` or others.

Comment: Avoiding scanf is wise.  However, if you want to use it, you could always just read one string at a time (eg, `if( 1 == scanf("%127s", cmd))` and then only attempt to read another if appropriate for the command.  If you want to tread newline differently than a space, you're much better off using `fgets`

Comment: I just do not understand how to use fgets().  I have watched the videos but I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: "if you run this program and input "Quit" for example, it should just exit" --> No, `"Quit"` and `"quit"` are different strings.

Comment: @Singo " just do not understand how to use fgets(). " is too broad.  Being specific about what application difficulties you have makes for a better question and better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example using `fgets` and `sscanf` to check the number of arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    struct cmd {
        const char *cmd;
        int arg_count;
        const char *help;
        const char *aux;
    } cmds[] = {
        { "quit", 0, "exit the program" },
        { "print", 0, "show contents of the tree in reverse sorted order" },
        { "add", 2, "insert the given key/val into the tree, "
            "duplicate keys are ignored", " <key> <val>" },
        { "get", 1, "print FOUND if the name is in the tree, "
            "NOT FOUND otherwise", " <key>" },
        { "clear", 0, "eliminate all key/vals from the tree" },
        { "size", 0, "print the total number of nodes in the tree" },
        { "preorder", 0, "print contents of the tree in pre-order which "
            "is how it will be saved" },
        { "save", 1, "write the contents of the tree in pre-order to "
            "the given file", " <file>" },
        { "load", 1, "clear the current tree and loads the one in "
            "the given file", " <file>" },
    };
    struct cmd *end = cmds +  sizeof cmds / sizeof *cmds;
    for( struct cmd *c = cmds; c < end; c++ ){
        char hdr[128];
        sprintf(hdr, "%s%s:", c->cmd, c->aux ? c->aux : "");
        printf("  %-17s%s\n", hdr, c->help);
    }

    char buf[128];
    char cmd[128];
    char input1[128];
    char input2[128];

    while( NULL != fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) ){
        int count = sscanf(buf, "%127s %127s %127s", cmd, input1, input2);
        struct cmd *c;
        for( c = cmds; c < end; c++ ){
            if( strcmp(cmd, c->cmd) == 0 ){
                if( count - 1 != c->arg_count ){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid cmd: %s",
                        buf);
                } else {
                    printf("valid cmd: %s", buf);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if( c == end ){
            fprintf(stderr, "command not found: %s\n", cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that this incorrectly identifies `add a b c` as a valid command and treats it the same as `add a b`.  Fixing that is fairly trivial and left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crude sketch of dealing with user input that may involve different numbers of parameters of different types. Perhaps this will get you started.

```
int main() {
    char buf[ 128 ]; // sufficient?

    for(;;) {
        printf(
            "\n"
            "crawl: blah\n"
            "walk: blah\n"
            "jog speed: blah\n"
            "drive min max: blah\n"
            "rip: blah\n"
            ">> "
        );
        fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin ); // user input

        char *p = strtok( buf, " \n" ); // first "word" isolated

        if( stricmp( p, "crawl" ) == 0 ) // case insensitive
            printf( "So cute!\n" );

        else if( stricmp( p, "walk" ) == 0 )
            printf( "Take out the garbage.\n" );

        else if( stricmp( p, "jog" ) == 0 ) {
            p = strtok( NULL, " \n" );
            printf( "You think you can sustain %dkph?\n", atoi(p) );
        }

        else if( stricmp( p, "drive" ) == 0 ) {
            int min = atoi( strtok( NULL, " \n" ) );
            int max = atoi( strtok( NULL, " \n" ) );
            printf( "Between %d and %d\n", min, max );
        }

        else if( stricmp( p, "rip" ) == 0 ) {
            printf( "Well remembered...\n" );
            break;
        }

        else
            printf( "Stick to the menu\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is a quick demonstration. A superior technique would assemble an array of 'prompt' words to be used, their explanation ("blah"), and a function pointer to a 'handler' function. This is left as an exercise for the reader.